# How to Use Nifi GetFTP to read ZOS files in gdg format(path.to.file.in.dotted.dir.format)

Tags: apache-nifi, mainframe, zos, hortonworks-dataflow

I'm Trying to read Mainframe files using nifi GetFTP, the files which are given as 'JS.XXXX.FLAT.XXXXDB' where as JS, XXX, FLAT being the directories and the file is referenced with absolute file path for file "XXXXDB" and instead of "/" we have "." here.

Nifi is not able to pull these files from the system, whereas I'm able to read from regular ftp,python ftp clients.

please help me know is there a way we can read these files in nifi.

I have tried using GetFTP, GetSFTP, ListFTP/FetchFTP and none of them seem to recognize these files from the backend.

in Python script I tried this and it worked.

```py
def ftp_data_file(data_file, ftp_file_nm):
    print("calling ftp_data_file")
    writefile = open(data_file, "w")
    print("file open for writing:"+data_file)
    # Transfer mode ASCII, replacing special chars with space
    chars = re.escape(string.punctuation)
    ftp.retrlines('RETR ' + ftp_file_nm, lambda s, w=writefile.write: w(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ' + chars + '\n]', ' ', s) + '\n'))
    writefile.close()
```

Comment: If your are talking zOS and not USS then JS, XXX and FLAT are not paths, they are parts of the dataset name (DSN). You mention GDG in your title - this is a naming method you use to give datasets of the same name a unique name. The generation is in the format GggggVvv (where vv is usually 00). So your example ata set name is JS.XXX.FLAT.GggggVvv. You can shorthand the .GDG reference to (0) for the latest dataset, (-1) for the next to latest etc. To get all datasets of the base name JS.XXX.FLAT simply omit the GDG reference. How you specify the DSN depends on the capabilities of this 'nifti'.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have mixed up the by adding zos tag. I couldn't add gdg tag to this post due to low reputation. Yes you are right this is for gdg files to be picked up by nifi which isn't working. I have tried (0), (-1),(1) version of GgggVvv file